# benthos read beautified json

Tags: go, benthos

I have a simple json

```
{
    "years": [ "2018", "2019" ]
}
```

that I want to read with Benthos. However as this is a "beautified" json, Benthos reads each line as message. How can one read this multiline json with benthos and compactify it for further downstream processors?

```
input:
  file:
    paths: [./init.json]
    codec: lines/multipart

pipeline:
  processors: ??

output:
  type: stdout
```

The pipeline should simply print the same in `stdout` as `jq -c ./init.json` would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```yaml
input:
  file:
    paths: [./init.json]
    codec: all-bytes

  processors:
    - mapping: |
        root = this.format_json()

output:
  stdout:
    codec: all-bytes
```

Also, note that the current release is V4, where `type: stdout` isn't how you specify the output. Details [here](https://www.benthos.dev/docs/components/outputs/about).

Comment: Ah thank you for the answer and the hint about concerning the output! I just add the line ` root = root.parse_json()` to the mapping such that I have the compactified json in a line. But I will accept your answer :)

Comment: The `this` keyword does JSON parsing implicitly if the input data is valid JSON. Otherwise, you get an error. I added `format_json()` so you get a pretty-printed JSON output.

Comment: thank you for the hint! so its simply `root = this`.

Comment: Yeah, that's the identity transform. In your case, it's helpful to have it if you want to validate the input JSON. Otherwise, it just passes it along to the output as raw bytes